# Angular 2 Component Factory Resolver Helper Function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have been working with the Component Factory Resolver for awhile and while I think it's pretty slick, there is one thing that drives me nuts. I would love to wrap most of the repeated code into a helper function that renders the component.

In my case I have a dashboard component where we render quite a few different components by altering singleton services to trigger visibility or not. Rather than having a ton of these create component code blocks, I was wondering if anyone has successfully create a helper-like function that a few variables can be passed into to achieve the same effect, thus eliminating a lot of the repetitive code.

Below is my attempt at a helper function and the call to activate it. The component gets created, but the destroy function doesn't work. I have narrowed it down to the Component Reference not actually being saved to the globally accessible component. Is there a way to store component references within a global array? If so how would you go about dynamically accessing them as components are added/destroyed?

**Subscription within ngOnInit**

```
    // Subscribe to Create User Modal Visibility
    this._ComponentVisibilityService.createUserVisibility$.subscribe(
        _createUserVisibility => {

            this.renderComponent(
                this.createUserModal,
                CreateUserComponent,
                this.createUserModalContainer,
                _createUserVisibility
            )
        }
    )
```

**Function within the dashboard component**

```
renderComponent(component, template, container, visibility) {

        if (visibility) {
            // Destroy previously built components if not already destroyed
            if (component) component.destroy();
            // Generate component factory
            const componentFactory = this._ComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(template);
            // Render the component
            component = container.createComponent(componentFactory);

        } else {
            // Destroy the component if visibility is false
            if (component) component.destroy()
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think you created `this.createUserModal` with the same logic that renderComponent has. Isn't it? If it's not, where `this.createUserModal` comes from?

Comment: `this.createUserModal` is just a global variable within the dashboard component. Traditionally that would be where you store the returned component from `createComponent`, and then call `this.createUserModal.destroy()` to dispose of it. The issue I am seeing (and it makes sense) is that saving `createComponent` to a function scoped variable basically renders the reference null once the function exits.

So I guess the real question is where to save the component references so they can be strategically interacted with at a later time.

Comment: As I see there's nothing wrong if you save `createUserModal: ComponentRef<any>` as a `DashboardComponent` property it should let you dispose it later, I'm using the same approach in a project.

Comment: Well like I said it works if I save it directly to the DashboardComponent property as you said above. The issue is when I try to implement the helper function. Let me ask you this: When I pass in `this.createUserModal` to the `renderComponent()` function does it pass in a reference, or copy the value of `this.createUserModal` to the `component` variable within the function. If it just copies it, then I would understand why `destroy` isn't working.

Comment: No, that's how JS works, non-primitive values are passed as reference

Comment: Okay, that was my original thought. But good to verify. I don't suppose I need to cast a type on the incoming variable to the function? I have the type set correctly on the component property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ended up doing some digging last night and found that Typescript considers `any` to be a basic (primitive) type. So from what I can tell, none of the methods, or structure are available to `component`, unless altered to not fit into the "basic" category, otherwise its passed as a value and not a reference. However, like in javascript, an object is not considered a primitive type so I refactored the component variable to be cast as an object with a property `component` as `ComponentRef<any>`, and it worked!

**Component Property Declaration**

```
createUserModal: { component: ComponentRef<any> } = { component: null }
```

**Function Declaration**

```
renderModal(component: { component: ComponentRef<any> }, template, container, visibility) {
    // Create Component...
}
```

This combination allows the object to passed in as a reference which in turn allows the function to alter the value of `DashboardComponent` property `this.createUserModal`, which in turn allows all of the methods to be called on it as normal.